# FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates not working on physical device

Tags: android

`FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates()` is working fine on the emulator but not working, I mean `onLocationResult()` callback is not getting called, on a physical device (i.e. on my Moto G4 Play). I can't figure out why

Comment: Well, network based location might require a SIM card and GPS typically doesn't work indoors, so how are you testing?

Comment: I'm using ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY and testing it on my real phone.. inside a room.. Do I have to test it outside?? That would make my app unusable..

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: If you want to use GPS, you need to go outside. Or at least close to a window or an open balcony door. But it still might not work. That really depends on the building. As a basic rule: GPS won't work indoors. If your app is based on the idea of using GPS indoors, then yes, that makes your app unusable. During development you can use the emulator or a fake GPS provider such as [Fake GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.newapphorizons.fakegps) or [Mock Locations](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gavrikov.mocklocations).

Comment: `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` depends on GPS.

Comment: Yes. The main idea is to get the device's location... As you've told me GPS won't work indoors, then the only possible solution is to go for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission with PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY. Anything else that I can do to get an accurate device location??

Comment: Thank you Markus..  I go out and my app  starts receiving location updates!!  and yes one has be outside for GPS to work..

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about the difference of `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` and `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`, but I'd imagine that with `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`you could also get less accurate cell tower based locations, if the GPS isn't available.